# Cropped InfoWindow when using Google Maps v3 directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

With GMap APi v3 I am using the directions service to generate a route for the user, but once the route is rendered on the map, the target infowindow I placed becomes cropped, as the map is centered on the route, not the target.

How can I tell GM to either:

1. Automatically focus (or center) on the infowindow, instead of the route
2. Show the infowindow in a way that it is not cropped (for example: using the tooltip arrow on the top right of the infowindow instead of the lower left, which causes the window to appear on the top right of the route target)

Comment: i tried calling .setCenter() and .panTo() on my map, but it does not work at all - i even tried making the calls after the direction service sends a response, but still - no usable results.

Comment: Do you have some sample code you can add to the question?

Comment: My code is too abstract and i thought as using the directions service is a common thing any code would not be required. In any case, i might have found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done by using .setCenter() within the directionsService callback (after receiving a proper response). However, this only worked when using a timeout. It may not be the purest solution, but it is the only one available to me at the moment.

```
/* _x & _y are passed as coordinates */
var _latLng=new google.maps.LatLng(_x,_y);
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            gmap.setCenter(_lagLng);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

It seems that if you call .setCenter() too early, gmap is still building up and once done, centering on the route - thus overriding your last command to .setCenter() - however, using the timeout as a workaround, the call is done after the map is built and the route rendered.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but here's a solution without setTimeout. You can use the 'tilesloaded' event:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsDisplay.setMap(gmap);

directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        var listener = gmap.addListener('tilesloaded', function(){

            // add your centering code here
            // or open your infowindow here and maps will auto center like expected

            google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);

        });
    }else{
        console.warn('Error retreiving directions');
    }
});
```